# How to fix django admin "add" button

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to web development, and i'm building a blog web app in Django.
I'm having problems adding new posts through django-admin. Clicking the "add" button gives me an `"Error during template rendering - 'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'"` error message.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default='date posted')

    def published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.post_date <= now
    published_recently.admin_order_field = 'post_date'
    published_recently.boolean = True
    published_recently.short_description = 'Recent post?'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Customer(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField(default='date reg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_cont = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    votes = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(default='date commented')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_cont


class Feedback(models.Model):
    feedback_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    feedback_detail = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, default=1, verbose_name='user_name', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Customer, Feedback, Comment


# Register your models here.
class CommentInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment
    extra = 1
    fields = ['comment_cont', 'votes', 'comment_date']


class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'country', 'reg_date']})
    ]


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Post', {'fields': ['title', 'content']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['post_date'], 'classes':['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [CommentInLine]
    list_display = ('title', 'content', 'post_date', 'published_recently')
    list_filter = ['post_date']
    search_fields = ['title']


class FeedbackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Feedback', {'fields': ['feedback_title', 'feedback_detail', 'user_name']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('user_name', 'feedback_title', 'feedback_detail')
#     inlines = [CustomerInLine]
#     list_display = ('user_name', 'feedback_title', 'feedback_detail')


class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['user_name', 'comment_post', 'comment_cont', 'votes', 'comment_date']


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(Feedback, FeedbackAdmin)
admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
admin.site.register(Comment, CommentAdmin)
```

I want to be able to add posts through Django admin. Any other corrections to the code is highly welcome. I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870088/django-attributeerror-datetime-date-object-has-no-attribute-utcoffset/51870283#51870283. Maybe one of your db columns is type date. Try running your migrations again. Try removing fields one by one from PostAdmin fieldset to help debug what field is giving you the trouble.

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you suggested, and i found the problem in the CommentInLine class. Thaks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post_date = models.DateTimeField(default='date posted')
```

the `post_date` is `DateTimeField` and you have provided a string as default . It should be an instance of datetime.datetime.

```
post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
# or
post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Publish Time')
```

should fix the problem

Comment: @MrUzo did the answer work ? If yes accept the answer so that it help others

Comment: Thanks. I tried both, still gives the same error message.

Comment: run a make migrations and then migrate

Comment: I belive this was part of the solution, but the main problem was the 'comment_date' in the CommenIntLine class. I took it out, and it fixed the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: ```comment_date = models.DateTimeField(default='date commented')```
 that was because of this as i mentioned in the answer you provided a string as default for a datetimefield ,