# AttributeError 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am relatively new with Django.

I have a models.py file with such attributes:

```
from datetime import *
from django.db import models

def return_date_time():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now + timedelta(days=10)

class Job(models.Model):
    lastDate = models.DateTimeField(default=return_date_time)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am able to create new database on /admin, but when editing I get This error

```
AttributeError at /admin/job/job/2/change/
'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
```

There was a very similar post here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870088/django-attributeerror-datetime-date-object-has-no-attribute-utcoffset](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
but I was not able to solve the problem

The Traceback is as below

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/job/job/2/change/

Django Version: 4.1.7
Python Version: 3.10.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'django_filters',
 'job.apps.JobConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
   'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
   9 :             {% for field in line %}
   10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
   11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
   12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
   14 :                     {% else %}
   15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}
   16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
   17 :                             <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                              {{ field.field }} 
   20 :                         {% endif %}
   21 :                     {% endif %}
   22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
   23 :                         <div class="help"{% if field.field.id_for_label %} id="{{ field.field.id_for_label }}_helptext"{% endif %}>
   24 :                           {{ field.field.help_text|safe }}
   25 :                         </div>
   26 :                     {% endif %}
   27 :                 </div>
   28 :             {% endfor %}
   29 :         </div>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 92, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 238, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 208, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 177, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 238, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 238, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 321, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 321, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1070, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1047, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 419, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 33, in __str__
    return self.as_widget() + self.as_hidden(only_initial=True)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 99, in as_widget
    return widget.render(
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 280, in render
    context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 89, in get_context
    context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 889, in get_context
    value = self.decompress(value)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 991, in decompress
    value = to_current_timezone(value)
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 241, in to_current_timezone
    if settings.USE_TZ and value is not None and timezone.is_aware(value):
  File "/Users/daniel/Workspace/Projects/iTokyo_Jobs/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 256, in is_aware
    return value.utcoffset() is not None

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/job/job/2/change/
Exception Value: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
```

Would anyone have any knowledge of what the problem is?
When I try to run makemigrations, it is stated that there is no changes to be made.

Answer (score 0):

The `lastDate` is a `DateTimeField` in the `Job` model. Try to use Django's `timezone` module to return a timezone-aware datetime object, instead of simply returning `datetime` object of Python through `datetime` module, so:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

def return_date_time():
    return timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=10)

class Job(models.Model):
    lastDate = models.DateTimeField(default=return_date_time)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Otherwise, you can simply drop the schema and recreate it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! It still seems to be having the same problem, even after using timezone. Could this be related to my postgresql db / migrations I have made?

Comment: @JeonghooSHIN Yes it's possible that issue may be with PostgreSQL, you can do several things such as: 1. Checking timezone setting in your PostgreSQL database, whether correctly set or not using `SHOW timezone` command.

Comment: @JeonghooSHIN you can also check `python manage.py showmigrations` This will show you a list of all the migrations of your database. Make sure that the migrations have been applied correctly and have not caused any issues with the timestamp data.

Comment: Hey thanks for all the help! Im not sure if it was best practice, but I dropped schema for my postgresql server and recreated it. It fixed the issue!